# push email / email server tutorial

Tags: server, email, dovecot

Does anyone happen to know the current status of push email in the linux world? From my searching at the moment I have seen Z-push http://www.ifusio.com/blog/setup-your-own-push-mail-server-with-z-push-on-debian-linux and https://peterkieser.com/2011/03/25/androids-k-9-mail-battery-life-and-dovecots-push-imap/

Are there other solutions? Does anyone have any experiences with these? They're somewhat different in that Z-push seems to work in conjunction with an existing imap server?

Some time ago I did manage to compile and build Dovecot 2 (since only Dovecot 1 was available in the Ubuntu repos at the time), it would have been a real fluke because I had no idea what I was doing but it seemed to work well with my mobile phone, that said, I can't say for sure that it was pushing, but it seemed like it.

Anyway, I'm here again and looking to set up a mail server. I'm hoping to do a better of a job this time around with virtual users and such.

Without installing ispconfig3 (or something similar), does anyone have any recent email server tutorials (that cover all aspects MTA, MDA...) that can supply push email on a Ubuntu 12.04 server?

(I'm probably of slightly above newb status, but not far)

Thanks a bunch

Comment: push doesn't seem to be a problem, I think for the most part I need a recent mail server tutorial that works with 12.04. I have tried using older ones only to come across config files that are slightly different etc. and ultimately a mangled setup.

Comment: What do you need exactly? "Push mail" is what the marketing machine is producing. Is IMAP-IDLE sufficient or do you need ActiveSync (more than mail)? And keep in mind that mail is not the easiest thing to configure, because of all the virtual domains, spamfilters, security, sorts of gateways, networking issues (port 25 blocked), etc. that comes into play. I have experience with *a lot in this*, including Z-push, but I can't answer your question in the current form. (would become a book)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the links you provided give 404 Not Found errors.

At first it's not clear whether you're asking about support for push email in MUAs or in servers (or perhaps in webmail servers?) although later in your question I guess you are talking about servers.

Dovecot, even version 1, supports IMAP IDLE (what's needed for so-called "push" email under IMAP) without any problems at all, and without any special configuration required. It "just works".

Furthermore, it would surprise me if Dovecot's competitors (courier? cyrus?) didn't also support it. But I only use Dovecot myself, so I don't know about the others.

Comment: thank you for the heads up about the links, they were shorted at one point in my composing of the question.

I'm not talking about webmail.

I didn't know that about Dovecot 1, but, either way 12.04 has Dovecot 2 in the repos now (I'm pretty sure based on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dovecot/)

So,push isn't a problem, but I am still looking for a complete and recent tutorial on how to set up a mail server with push capabilities. I've tried to follow old ones, resulting in issues.

I have a bit of experience with Dovecot, thus it is preferred, but I'm not against courier or the others.

Comment: As I said, you don't have to configure anything special. Follow ANY tutorial for setting up Dovecot's IMAP server, and you will have push capability.

Comment: Have any links? I'd love to follow the official documentation but they are out dated, for example https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix "this guide has been tested on Ubuntu 6.06 (Dapper) and Ubuntu 7.10 (Gutsy)" or   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DovecotLDAP "Was done on a vanilla installation of Ubuntu 8.04.2" and the howtoforge perfect server stuff tends to use ispconfig. I understand what you're saying but there is still a lack of tutorials for postfix+dovecot+spamassassin... for Ubuntu 12.04.